# Testing CXF Client with Spring WS Test

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, spring-ws

According to the documentation you can nicely test your WS client using http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/test/client/MockWebServiceServer.html server.

But there is one precondition your client has to

```
   // MyWebServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport, and is configured in applicationContext.xml
   @Autowired
   private MyWebServiceClient client;
```

extend WebServiceGatewaySupport.

My question is what if I am using another implementation for instance CXF. Is there any exisiting mock server implementation which supports CXF clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The spring-ws-test module is specific to Spring-WS and cannot be used with other frameworks. You can use SoapUI for that, for instance.

Comment: I could test without soapui with my own 'mocked' instance of the jaxws:server. Though would be great to have something like Spring-WS test mock like there is for WebServiceGatewaySupport.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a [simple JUnit rule](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) which lets you mock with a server in CXF. Basically configure your clients using properties, then point them to a webservice instance which delegates to a mock object.